# Yii2: How to load a JSON into a GridView?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, yii2

I have a JSON object called `response` that is a response from a server. It is produced here:

```
<?php
$this->registerJs(<<<JS
    $(function($) {
        function reloadGridView(idColor) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/colors?idcolor=" + idColor,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(res) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
                    $.pjax.reload({container: "#gridColors"});
                }
            });
        }

        $('#myCkeckbox).on('click', function(e) {
            var idColor = $('#idPerson').val();
            reloadGridView(idPerson);

        });
    });
JS
);
?>
```

Here is the `response` object:

```
[
    {
        "number": 1,
        "name": "Orange"
    },
    {
        "number": 2,
        "name": "White"
    },
]
```

I want to show it in the next `GridView` using **jQuery** but I don't know how to do it, because `respose` is **JavaScript** and `GridView` is **PHP**.

```
<?
Pjax::begin(['id' => 'gridColors']);
echo GridView::widget([
    'summary' => '',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'number',
        'name'
    ],
]);
Pjax::end();
?>
```

Comment: You can't populate a GridView dynamically from javascript.  It wasn't designed to do this.  The only way to achieve this would be to send your JSON data back to PHP via jQuery.ajax or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this...

```
use yii\helper\Json;
use yii\data\ArrayDataProvider;

$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    // Define data array by decoding json-string in $jsonResponseString
    // Converted from your Json object somehow...
    'allModels' => Json::decode($jsonResponseString),
    // Might need this too... (assuming number is unique identifier)
    'key' => 'number',
    // Setup sorting if not using default
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => ['number', 'name'],
    ],
    // Set pagination if not using default
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
]);

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'number',
        'name',
    ],
]);
```

This code is NOT tested, but hopefully will give some help.

Comment: My JSON called "response" is JavaScript code, so Json::decode($response) can't be executed.

Comment: Aha, now I understand. Like Lucas commented above, you need to send the Json data to PHP first. Describe that part in more detail... eg where does your Json data come from?